# When can one choose a fibration of a product manifold such that a given vector field is vertical?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $M,N$ be two differentiable manifolds, and let $V$ be a vector field on $M\times N$. What conditions on $V$ enable the existence of a fibration $\pi:M\times N\to M$ such that $V$ is tangent to the fibres?

Comment: A necessary condition: the closures of the orbits of $V$ must have dimension at most that of $N$.